# using test plumbing from an internal dependency

Tags: rust

I do not know what the correct terminology is so I guessed at 'internal dependency'.

I have in cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0"
thing = { path = "./thing"}
.....
```

I cannot change this. Inside 'thing' there are multiple tests. Plus a bunch of code used for creating those tests (what I called 'plumbing').

Like this

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
   fn setup_testable_thingy(){
      ...
   }
   fn remove_testable_thingy(){
      ...
   }
   etc
```

in `thing/src/bit/mod.rs`

I need to use those plumbing things to create tests in the main part of the code base

But when I do this

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    pub use thing::bit::tests::{setup_testable_thingy, remove_testable_thingy};
```

in `src/submod/part.cs` the compiler complains that there is no such thing as `thing::bit::tests`

Note that `thing::bit::not_test_func` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use private modules and functions from one crate in another crate. You'll have to copy them or make them public.

Comment: what makes it private? Can I make it public?

Comment: i tried `pub mod tests` but that made no diference

Comment: @pm100 You also have to move them outside of `cfg(test)` as only the root crate is built with `test`.

Comment: even with `cargo test --workspace`?

Comment: @pm100 that builds and tests each crate individually. The subcrate will be built as test and tested, but the root crate will still depend on the non-test subcrate. Found this issue, with the solution being to make a feature: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8379

Comment: woohoo - that worked . Take your tick